# How to keep Assert failure data

Tags: c#, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I'm using VS2013/CodedUI and in my [TestMethod] I assert as following:

```
Assert.IsTrue(String.Equals(logo.GetModifiedBy(), "Vendor2"));
```

And this fails as expected in my test case but the message in the Output is simply as shown below, is there a way to also report the data used to compare? I searched but didn't find much

```
Message: Assert.IsTrue failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`Assert.AreEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx):

```
Assert.AreEqual("Vendor2", logo.GetModifiedBy());
```

The exception message generated will indicate both the expected and actual value.

Of course, you could also just provide a custom message using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243768.aspx) of `IsTrue`:

```
var modifiedBy = logo.GetModifiedBy();
Assert.IsTrue(
    String.Equals(modifiedBy, "Vendor2"), 
    "Incorrect ModifiedBy value: '{0}'", 
    modifiedBy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Each Assert method has an overload that takes a string message.  The following would give you what you want, although I agree with @p.s.w.g that Assert.AreEqual() is probably what you want.  Assert.AreEqual() also supports a custom message.

```
Assert.IsTrue(String.Equals(logo.GetModifiedBy(), "Vendor2"), string.Format("{0} does not match {1}", logo.GetModifiedBy(), "Vendor2"));
```